# Getting error while positioning cdk overlay

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using angular material cdk I want to open overlay at center screen. Following suggestions from here and other resources I created [this test code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-he4grl). The overlay is opened at the center of the screen as I want but when I try to dismiss it or reopen it there is an error:

> ERROR
> Error: positionStrategy.setOrigin is not a function

So not really sure what causing that and it preventing from control to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the directive `cdkConnectedOverlay` only works for "connected divs"

To create a "modal" manually you can use four variables, one for the overLayRef, one to get the template -using ViewChild-  and two more to subscriptions and create three functions

```
  @ViewChild('template', { static: true }) template: TemplateRef<any>;
  overlayRef: OverlayRef;
  opened: Subscription=null;
  keyESC:Subscription=null;

  private showControl() {
    // if not exist the overlayRef, we create
    if (!this.overlayRef) {

      //the position strategy
      const config = this.overlay
        .position()
        .global()
        .centerHorizontally()
        .centerVertically();

      //add as property hasBackdrop
      this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
        positionStrategy: config,
        hasBackdrop: true,
        
      });
    }

    //be sure that it's nothing attached
    if (!this.overlayRef.hasAttached())
      this.overlayRef.attach(  //and attach
        new TemplatePortal(this.template, this.viewContainerRef)
      );

    //we subscribe to overlayRef.backdrop click
    if (!this.opened)
      this.opened = this.overlayRef
        .backdropClick()
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe((_) => {
          this.isControlVisible = false;
        });
  }

  private hideControl() {
    //unsubscribe to the observables

    this.opened && this.opened.unsubscribe();
    this.keyESC && this.keyESC.unsubscribe();
    this.opened = null;
    this.keyESC = null;
    if (this.overlayRef && this.overlayRef.hasAttached()) this.overlayRef.detach();
  }

  //create an observable to listen the ESC key in "document"
  private controlESC()
  {
    if (!this.keyESC)
      this.keyESC=fromEvent(document,'keydown').pipe(
      filter((x:any)=>x.keyCode==ESCAPE),
      take(1)).subscribe(_=>{
      this.isControlVisible=false;
    })
  }
```

Then you can use a getter

```
  get isControlVisible() {
    return this._isControlVisible;
  }
  set isControlVisible(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.showControl();
      this.controlESC();
    } else this.hideControl();

    this._isControlVisible = value;
  }
```

Remember in constructor inject OVerlay and viewContainerRef. It's neccessary to attach a [templatePortal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview)

```
constructor(
    public overlay: Overlay,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}
```

And in ngOnDestroy call to hideControl

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.hideControl();
    this.overlayRef && this.overlayRef.dispose();
  }
```

NOTE: To avoid the input get the focus when click the icon use stopPropagation

```
<button
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation();isControlVisible = true"
    matSuffix
  >
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nygnfh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** Creating a directive.

Well, we can think in a directive for this work.

If rename the function hideControl() and showControl() by simple hide() and show(), we can use some like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[pop-up]',
  exportAs: 'PopUp',
})
export class PopUpDirective implements OnDestroy {

  overlayRef: OverlayRef;
  opened: Subscription = null;

  //I choose in this case use a @HostHistener
  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape') _() {
    this.hide();
  }
```

In constructor we inject futthermore the own template

```
  constructor(
    public overlay: Overlay,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private template: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {}
```

And work like

```
<button (click)="bt.show()">Show</button>

<ng-template [pop-up] #bt="PopUp">
  ...
  <button (click)="bt.hide()">
</ng-template>
```

a [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lybxp9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpop-up.directive.ts)